# Access app works perfectly in regular Access 2016 but gives errors in runtime Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

When I run the app on full version of Access 2016 it works perfectly and compiles with no errors. However on Access 2016 RUNTIME I receive errors. I have narrowed the first error down to the following line of VBA code, as it runs well until it hits this code:

```
Me.Filter = "Argument = 'Default'"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

Any ideas why this is occurring? The 'error number' is 2001.

EDIT: Apparently there is an issue with using Access filters with an SQL Server back end... Is this still the case? Changing every filter instance to recordsource where clauses in my code would be very time consuming.

Comment: Perhaps Argument is a reserved word? Try: `Me.Filter = "[Argument] = 'Default'"`.

Comment: It wasn't that unfortunately, good suggestion though!

Comment: Is it only this form, or do other forms behave similarly? Could be caused by corruption; try to delete the offending code block and _retype_ it from scratch (no copy-paste).

Comment: Compact & Repair?

Comment: SOLVED: I noticed that these two lines were in the Form_Open event for my form and moved them to the Form_Load event. This fixed the problem. It doesn't really explain why it worked in the full version of Access and not in Access runtime but ah well, hope this helped someone!

Comment: The form data isn't available until after the form Open event. Normally form Load is the best place to do anything related to the form itself.

Comment: Yes, just strange that this error would only occur in runtime. Thanks I'll bear that in mind in the future!